# Which country in Europe offers Macbook Air 13" with US keyboard (with wide enter)?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, apple-store

I would like to buy a **Macbook Air**, but I don't like the small and narrow <kbd>Enter</kbd> (return) key, small left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the extra keys that you can buy in Czech stores/eshops that sell Apple products.

This is what I do NOT like:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

I really hate the small <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the small left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the extra keys. Could somebody help me where in Europe (which country) or maybe in nearby regions (North Africa, Israel or maybe some country in the Middle East) can I buy Macbook Air 13" with US keyboard?

Comment: A few years ago it wasn't possible, but now the Swiss Apple Store offers English keyboards with *any* Mac, don't you have that option in the Czech Apple store? There are 3 Apple retail stores in Switzerland: in Zurich, Geneva and Wallisellen, consult this link: http://www.apple.com/retail/storelist/ for more information.

Comment: Hardware shopping questions are off-topic. You'll want to edit this to encourage an answer that teaches people how things are built rather than asking someone to find you the part you want.

Comment: Funny. I really hate the one-row enter key.

Answer (score 5):

What about store.apple.com?

[image]
[image]

I have bought two Macs with a US keyboard from the Finnish store. US means the standard US layout with a single row return key. The International English and UK layouts have a two row return key.

You can probably get them from eBay as well.